# R predict() asking for variable excluded in lm() regression model

Tags: r, lm, predict

I intend to apply a regression based on two "x" variables, excluding others present in a dataframe.

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Paul", "Charles", "Edward", "Iam"),
             age = c(18, 20, 25, 30),
             income = c( 1000, 2000, 2500, 3000),
             workhours = c(35, 40, 45, 40))

regression <- lm(income ~ . -name, data = df)
```

I face a problem when I try to use the predict function. It demands information about the "name" variable:

```
predict(object = regression,
    data.frame(age = 22, workhours = 36))
```

It gives the following message error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'name' not found

I've **solved** this problem by excluting the "name" variable from the lm() function:

```
regression2 <- lm(income ~ . , data = df[, -1])
predict(object = regression2,
    data.frame(age = 22, workhours = 36))
```

Since I have **many** variables I intend to exclude from the regression, is there a way to solve this inside de predict() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `update`

```
> regression <- update(regression, . ~ .)
> predict(object = regression,
+     data.frame(age = 22, workhours = 36))
       1 
1714.859
```

Comment: Thank you as always, akrun!

Comment: why this problem happens, and why your solution works?

Comment: @robertspierre When the predict.lm is called, it calls `model.frame` and there is `xlev` argument which gets the `regression$xlevels` name as it is in the formula.  By updating it becomes a 0 length list i.e. `update(regression, . ~ .)$xlevels#
named list()` versus `regression$xlevels#
$name
[1] "Charles" "Edward"  "Iam"     "Paul"`, this does triggers the error as in the original model, 'name' is present, but the newdata given doesn't have that info